# Exception Module Test C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, exception

I ran into a problem while testing exceptions in a method. I get an error With C2337 ExpectedException: attribute not found.

```
    void Railcar::AddPlace(std::string name, unsigned int number)
   {
       if (number > PlaceVector.size())
            throw std::exception("Place not found");

       if (PlaceVector[number - 1].GetNamePassenger() != " ")
            throw std::exception("Place is occup");

       PlaceVector[number - 1] = Place(number, name);
    }


    [ExpectedException("Place not found")]
    TEST_METHOD(RailcarAddPlaceExseptionTest)
    {
        Railcar railcar(Luxury, 50, 1);
        railcar.CreatePlase();

        auto func = [&railcar] { railcar.AddPlace("John Titor", 51); };

        Assert::ExpectException<int>(func);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes in C++ are not like attributes in C# in that you cannot define custom attributes.

here's a list of available C++ attributes:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/attributes?view=vs-2019

Comment: Am I able to check the type of exception? [[noreturn]] gets any exception, I would like to separate them if possible.

Comment: @Gogogo You can by using `try...catch` that is `try { ... } catch (const ArgumentException& ex) { ... } catch (const ParameterException& ex) {...}`